# Explain this service control utility command

Tags: service, command-line, command, controls, restart

I am trying to understand what the following command does and where i can run it

```
srvctl [service_name] stop/start
```

Is that command restarting a service?(only a windows service?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start or stop a service in Windows you can execute the comand: net start/stop [service name]. I cannot tell you for sure what the command srvctl does, but you may find this helpful: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/rac.102/b14197/srvctladmin.htm